# Access vagrant VMs from inside docker container

Tags: docker, networking, vagrant

How do I setup a network between 2 centos VM's using Vagrant/Virtualbox and a docker container using docker for mac. They all need to be able to access each other.

Currently I'm not able to access the vm's from within a docker container.

Vagrant setup:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

   config.vm.define "build" do |build|
      build.vm.box = "centos/7"
      build.vm.provider "virtualbox"
      build.vm.hostname = "server-a"
      build.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
   end

   config.vm.define "test" do |test|
      test.vm.box = "centos/7"
      test.vm.provider "virtualbox"
      test.vm.hostname = "server"
      test.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.5"
   end
end
```

The vm's can access each other but the docker container can't access the vm's

```
docker network create -d bridge --gateway=192.168.50.1 --subnet=192.168.50.1/24 mybridge
docker run --network=mybridge alpine ping 192.168.50.4
=> not able to connect
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to connect network where you run a docker container and a network where you boot vagrant VMs to the same bridge device on your host machine:

**1.** Create docker network:

```
docker network create -d bridge --gateway=192.168.50.1
--subnet=192.168.50.1/24 mybridge
```

Docker creates bridge with name `br-<network_id>` on host machine:

```
$ docker network ls | grep mybridge
e13b3ccc6691        mybridge              bridge              local

$ brctl show | grep e13b3ccc6691
br-e13b3ccc6691     8000.024277661b29   no  

$ ip r s | grep e13b3ccc6691
192.168.50.0/24 dev br-e13b3ccc6691  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.50.1 linkdown
```

**2.** Connect vagrant VMs network to the same bridge device:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.define "build" do |build|
      build.vm.box = "centos/7"
      build.vm.provider "virtualbox"
      build.vm.hostname = "server-a"
      build.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.50.4", bridge: "br-e13b3ccc6691"
   end

   config.vm.define "test" do |test|
      test.vm.box = "centos/7"
      test.vm.provider "virtualbox"
      test.vm.hostname = "server"
      test.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.50.5", bridge: "br-e13b3ccc6691"
   end
end
```

**3.** Boot VMs:

```
$ vagrant up
```

**4.** Start docker container in `mybridge` network:

```
$ docker run -ti --network=mybridge alpine ping -c2 192.168.50.4
PING 192.168.50.4 (192.168.50.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.50.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.898 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.4: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.869 ms

--- 192.168.50.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.869/0.883/0.898 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the great response, I've got this working on a linux workstation. 
However using "docker for mac" I'm not able to bridge the network. When looking further into "docker for mac" docs, it seems it's a known limitation. :) 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds

Comment: I've followed those instructions and both VMs and Docker containers can ping each other, but while the VMs can access to the internet, Docker containers can't. Docker containers can't access to ports exposed by VMs neither.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed `Vagrantfile` does not work on this environment:

- OS: Debian bullseye (testing)
- Vagrant: 2.2.14
- Vagrant provider: libvirt (KVM)

This is the line that works:

```
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.50.4", dev: "br-e13b3ccc6691", mode: "bridge", type: "bridge"
```

My guess, because the provider.