# Connecting Vagrant VMs and Docker containers to the same bridge network

Tags: docker, networking, vagrant

I have followed the instructions at this question's answer to connect both Vagrant VMs and Docker containers to the same bridge network: [Access vagrant VMs from inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507357/access-vagrant-vms-from-inside-docker-container). The status of the networking is the following:

- Both containers and VMs can ping each other correctly.
- VMs and containers can't connect to ports exposed by each other using curl.
- VMs have internet access, while containers don't.
- I can't access to the container from the host through exposed port (neither through localhost or containers IP).
- I can access correctly to ports exposed by VMs from the host and over the network.

I have created the network this way:

```
docker network create -d bridge --gateway=192.168.51.1 --subnet=192.168.51.0/24 my-bridge
```

The Docker container:

```
docker run -ti -p 8912:8080 -v ${PWD}:/workdir --network my-bridge --name mycontainer myimage /bin/bash
```

And the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.define "management" do |management|
    management.vm.box = "centos/7"
    management.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.51.50", bridge: "br-4ab95f14d7eb"
    management.vm.hostname = "myhostname"

    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 32769, host: 32769
    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 32768, host: 32768
    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8081
    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8443, host: 8082
    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6080, host: 6080
    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 61880, host: 61880
    management.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6182, host: 6182

    management.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 8192
      v.cpus = 4
    end
```

end

Being br-4ab95f14d7eb the bridge network:

```
# docker network ls | grep my-bridge
# 4ab95f14d7eb        my-bridge          bridge              local
# brctl show | grep 4ab95f14d7eb
# br-4ab95f14d7eb       8000.02423ffbd644   no
```